# ERROR in rc_mpu_calibrate_accel_routine, center of fitted ellipsoids(in beagle bone blue)

Tags: linux, embedded, hardware, accelerometer, beagleboneblack

i am trying to calibrate the accelerometer in beagle bone blue (we have implemented our own board) i am working in Linux platform. i am facing this this error in few boards

> ERROR in rc_mpu_calibrate_accel_routine, center of fitted ellipsoids

in few boards while calibrating it doesn't have any errors. its working fine. i am using the same code in all the boards. even though the orientation was held in correct way, i am getting this error.

i have tried to debug step by step by printing there value. i am getting different values in working and not working boards. i assume there might be issue in hardware/components in the board. but i couldn't find the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.